# Fetch Configuration from Spring Cloud Config over SSL

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-config

I am building microservices using Spring Boot where configuration is distributed using Spring Cloud Config. Config application has SSL enabled.

I want my spring boot application to communicate to Config server over https. Problem is that before loading SSL configuration from bootstrap.yml, application initiates a rest call to Config Server to fetch the configuration and fails miserably with error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://host:8888/abcd/development,production": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
```

I have configured a truststore with CA certificate in bootstrap.yml:

```
# MicroServices Properties
spring:
  application:
     name: abcd
  profiles:
    active: development,production
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: https://<host>:8888 
      fail-fast: true
      password: abc@123
      username: user
server:
  ssl:
    trust-store: D:/Certs/caCert/server.p12
    trust-store-password: keystore
    key-store-provider: PKCS12
```

Any suggestions what should I do to create successful SSL communication with Config Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved after I imported CA certificate in JRE certificate store:

```
keytool -importcert -alias startssl -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -file ca.der
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has issue in finding the cert file. I would try something like this.

```
   ssl:
      trust-store: file:/Certs/caCert/server.p12
```

Even better, I would add my certificate into a keystore file using keytool so I can access my keystore file like

```
   ssl:
      enabled: true
      key-store: file:/Certs/keystore
      key-password: keypwd
```