# Spring Boot microservice cannot connect to config-server through https

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, https, keystore, truststore

I've successfully changed all my microservices into calling on each other's REST APIs through https instead of the default http. Only the config-server is left and something keeps going wrong. Currently trying to connect with it through `spring.cloud.config.uri=https://localhost:8888/my-config-server` defined in its `bootstrap.properties` file. My `application.properties` defines the stores like this:

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:SSL.jks
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
server.ssl.key-store-password=Password!
server.ssl.key-alias=SSL
```

Trying to connect to the config-server throws this:

```
I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8888/my-config-server: PKIX path building failed
[...]
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

This isn't a new error to me since I ran into this while connecting other services to the api-gateway, I solved that by using `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", ...);`. However, this doesn't seem to do anything for the config server. I've turned on `-Djavax.net.debug=all` but I'm quite new to this, so I don't really know what to make of it. What I can tell you for certain is that a

```
"ClientHello": {
  "client version": "TLSv1.2" .....
```

is present, followed by a

```
"ServerHello": {
  "server version": "TLSv1.2" ....
```

it fails once it reaches the following:

```
Consuming server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificate": {
  "certificate_request_context": "",
  "certificate_list": [  
  {
    "certificate": {
      "version": "v3" ....
```

this becomes a `Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed`. I've double checked that my applications accept TLSv1.2, as well as TLSv1.3. I generated the keystore using keytool commands:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias SSL -keyalg RSA -keypass Password! -storetype PKCS12 -keystore SSL.jks -validity 1095 -keysize 2048
```

Am I missing something? I feel like I'm quite lost on this implementation.

Edit: the path building error shows up in the microservice and not the config-server. The config-server seems to start up fine on its own and doesn't throw any errors/warnings

Answer (score 1):

So I assumed that it was kind of a loading problem. The config-server runs on https but the other properties haven't loaded any of the keys/certs yet during bootstrapping! So I followed [this](https://piotrminkowski.com/2019/12/03/secure-spring-cloud-config/) and forced all my microservices to load these configurations during bootstrapping. The key is this line from the tutorial:

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration = pl.piomin.services.account.SSLConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding these parameters when running your application.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/app/security/truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=myTrustStorePassword
```

I personally solved certification issue by manually adding certification from browser into JVM by following this very steps:
https://connect2id.com/blog/importing-ca-root-cert-into-jvm-trust-store

Comment: can this be added to be run on initialize within the program instead of JVM parameters? I've seen this suggested elsewhere but decided against it because it didn't sound ideal for production.

Comment: Actually I think it is better to add it outside of code if you mean adding statically within Configuration.java files. For example if you change your certification or DevOps decides to change it for various reasons, you would have to change your code. If you mean adding it within .yml file without ENV variable, there is a store password going around. I wouldn't want to expose that in git repository by adding it into .yml files. So I see no harm adding it with JVM parameters. However I also failed to find a solution to add it with ENV parameters which I believe would be another valid solution.

Comment: is using ```System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore, PATH)``` the same as the parameters? Setting that property worked for me in another service but it seems that the config-server specifically doesn't accept this. I don't know what's different.

Comment: Yes I believe it should do the trick. Since config server throws no exception I believe there might be something wrong either in your path or with your certification. Did you add any certification into your keystore PATH?

Comment: I generated a keypair and it seems to work microservice to microservice, just not microservice to config-server. I assume it's because it tries to call it in the bootstrap phase but I'm not sure what is happening within that phase.

Comment: Just to be sure did you follow this step when you add your .cer into your keystore? 
`keytool -importcert -alias startssl -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -file ca.`  source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044128/fetch-configuration-from-spring-cloud-config-over-ssl

Comment: could I add this cacert into my program? As far as I understand, this lets my machine run but wouldn't for others that get this self signed certificate later.

Comment: What it does is actually adding your cacert into keystore which happens to be in default java directory. If you want to share it you just need to point out path on other non-java programs or you can simply create another keystore in another directory and let your program know about this path by simply adding parameter. Just when you create another keystore don't forget to add cacert that you need.